# Best way to write a udf in vertica, where I need to refer to data from one of the rate table and write a formula on top

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions, vertica

I am planning to write a udf which can return the new value based on the rate setup for a specific date in a table, which means i need to write a query in udf
1. is it recommended as there are not enough example which refers to a table in udf
2. what are the other ways to solve this as Vetica procedural function does not allow to query within the function sql how it works in plsql

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is not clear but a UDF function can be used. Below is the pseudocode

```
CREATE FUNCTION updateRate(x DATE) RETURN INT
   AS BEGIN 
     RETURN (<your logic on updating rate> ); 
   END;
```

And then call the function in update query

> =>Update Mytable set rate=updateRate(colDate);